# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class XXX

Tags: android

An user has this crash (it's the first time!). I can't understand why, it's crazy...

This user setup: Galaxy S6 Edge on Android 7.0

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompagny/com.mycompagny.ui.form.FormPreviewActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.mycompagny.ui.widget.IconView
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.mycompagny.ui.widget.IconView
```

Have you got some explanations guys?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Something extraordinary in `IconView` class?

Comment: Maybe use AppCompat versions of widgets, like AppCompatImageView, etc. when extending and using in layouts.

Comment: Nothing, this class is the same since 1 year! No change on it.

Comment: lazy load that view using viewstub,